# Is there a word that means "a group containing just 1 member?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that can be used to describe a group or collection that only has 1 member/element? I first thought of *singleton*, but in my context *singleton* has a well-established meaning and I want to avoid confusion.

I want to ask a question like, "Does the group contain only one member?" with a more succinct, "Is the group a <*insert-word-here*>?" An analogous one would be: to ask if the group contains no elements, "Is the group empty?"

Put another way: *empty* is to "group with 0 elements" as <*?*> is to "group with 1 element."

"Bonus points" for a word that helps answer this more specific question succinctly: "Does the group contain only *this one specific* member?"

---

Clarification: The "group" can have different number of elements at different times. Subsequently, in that context a "group" ("collection" if you prefer that word.; eg, a Set, List, Array, etc) can contain 0 or more elements and still be a valid "group")

Comment: Reminder: comments are to ask for **clarification.** If your comment has been removed here, it's because it didn't contribute to that.

Comment: Can you clarify what sort of "group" you are thinking of? Group of people? Collection/list of items in a computer data structure? Or ...

Comment: Would a more succinct way to say "an individual that is the only member of its kind" work for you? "Group of 1" is harder, since groups, by definition, usually consist of more than one member. If it really needs to be a term for a group, do you want a term that means "a group that can only fit one member" or instead "a group that only currently contains one member, but there's room for more"?

Comment: @1006a I definitely mean the latter. The question is an "at this moment" one (that's another single-word-request question, I guess :-)), as opposed to the "can only fit one member" one.

Comment: @JamesRandom I added some clarification to the question based on your comments.

Comment: @E-Riz Maybe "container" is a better word than "group" in this context?

Comment: @JamesRandom yes, probably so in my particular context. I was specifically trying to avoid introducing too much computer programming context into the question for fear of getting close-voted as off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking for some type of technial word. And See also the closed [Can you call two things a “group”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354389/can-you-call-two-things-a-group)

Comment: @E-Riz Sorry for asking you to reveal more detail. It sent as predicted. At least you got some good answers before "they" came for you!

Comment: @user It isn't asking for a technical word. The context may be programming, but the user explicitly said they didn't want any of the standard technical terms.

Comment: Just so people know, the title has been changed to make the question appear off topic.

Comment: I just reverted the title. @user please do not change it again, you are altering the intent and spirit of my original question and that's not friendly SE behavior.

Comment: My edit indicated word-for-word a clarification you provided in a comment (now erased). Such edits are often done.

Comment: what a re re. who actually would ask this question LOL @E-Riz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although 'unary', that is,

> **3.** Composed of a single item or element.
>
> [*OED Online*](http://oed.com/)

(alternatively defined [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A%20unary) and [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unary)) is an adjective, it suits your desire for succinctness if the article is omitted: "Is the group *unary*?"

Comment: Your OED link doesn't seem to work. Maybe this: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unary

Comment: @JamesRandom, thanks, but that is not where the definition came from. The quote is correctly attributed and the link works (for me; the definition is possibly behind a paywall for you).

Comment: Nope, the link isn't useful.; it just points to the home page of the OED website. I don't think SE answers should point to sites you have to subscribe to and pay for as references. My opinion.

Comment: @E-Riz, precisely. That, *OED Online*, is where the quote came from. The link would be broken if it pointed to the definition...unless you have a login and are logged in. "Isn't useful" is not "broken", and my opinion differs. The use is attribution, not access.

Comment: See my edited comment that crossed yours mid-fight. I edited the answer with two additional links that *anyone* can view. If my edits are approved (or you edit it yourself) I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @E-Riz The publicly accessible version of the Oxford definition of *unary* is [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unary).

Comment: @JEL A link directly to the OED definition would not be broken. If you have access, it would take you straight to the definition; if you do not, it would take you to the front page, that is, the same page as you have linked to here (albeit with the login box visible). That would, in my view, be _less_ broken than linking straight to the front page. I’m not convinced that a link to a front page is adequate to satisfy the [attribution policy](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), which specifically mentions a **direct link**.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, we disagree, then. I'd argue the point on several grounds ("less broken", definition of 'site', definition of "direct link", etc.), but this *site* (ELU) is not suited to reasoned argument. As a matter of convenience, linking to the definition is superior, granted. As a matter of correct attribution with a soupçon (all I can independently provide) of marketing support, linking to the *OED* site *seems* superior to me.

Answer (score 5):

Singleton is used in computer programming (eg a class that can only have one instance) and in mathematics. For example, for a set containing only one element:

> In mathematics, a singleton, also known as a unit set,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)) is a set with exactly one element. For example, the set {0} is a singleton.
>
> The term is also used for a 1-tuple (a sequence with one member).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics))

If the word singleton is unacceptable then maybe **unit set**, **1-tuple** or **unitary** might be better. These all have their own existing meanings in computing and/or mathematics so might also cause confusion.

Comment: The OP explicitly wants to avoid using  *singleton*

Comment: Thanks. Edited the answer to make the options more explicit (and add another one).

Answer (score 3):

In American accounting, a type of business arrangement is the Limited Liability Company (LLC). An LLC can have several members or a single member. The Internal Revenue Service classifies an LLC with a lone member as a **single-member** LLC.

Answer (score 1):

The succinct question could be phrased as "Is the the group an individual?", but that isn't exactly an answer for the broader question, since *individual* doesn't usually imply a group.

The usual phrasing (rather than being a single word) is "[committee of one](http://committee%20of%20one)"